# Moongose schema not defined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using moongose with express.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new Schema({ //error
  name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

There's an error in above code. I wonder what's wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to define the **[`Schema`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)** object:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; // <-- you forgot to define it here

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    }
});
```